# Как рисовать на картинке?

Tags: php, javascript

Как правильно организовать и что использовать для решения задачи:

Пользователь загрузил картинку и нужно дать возможность пользователю нанести на картинку линии (или какие-то точки) и сохранить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно окунуться в мир удивительного `canvas`.

У контекста канваса есть метод [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), который позволяет добавить изображение на холст.

Далее вопрос с рисованием: тут нужно написать обработчик события нажатия мышки и при его вызове рисовать по координатам точки/узоры, что вы там хотите.

Для сохранения канваса, как картинки, используйте [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). Получаете `url`, и генерите из него картинку на том же сервере ( либо на клиенте, а потом скачиваете на сервер )

Comment: А дальше сохранить координаты canvas в базу и после при выводе наносить на картинку?

Comment: @Fitstd, забыл про эту часть вопроса) Обновил

Comment: @Fitstd, ну или если вам нужно только то, что нарисовал пользователь, тогда да, используйте ваш вариант